# Equivalente hide e show em CSS

Tags: css, html5, css3

O código abaixo não é executado em todos os navegadores:

```
<button id="btn">
    <img class="" 
         src="/img/icone-formation.png" 
         height="100%" 
         width="100%" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('f1').style.display ='initial'; 
                  document.getElementById('f2').style.display ='none';  
                  document.getElementById('f3').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f4').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f5').style.display ='none';
                  document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('id', 'press');">
</button>

<button id="btn">
    <img class="" 
         src="/img/icone-formation.png" 
         height="100%" 
         width="100%" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('f2').style.display ='initial'; 
                  document.getElementById('f1').style.display ='none';  
                  document.getElementById('f3').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f4').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f5').style.display ='none';
                  document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('id', 'press');">
</button>

<button id="btn">
    <img  class="" 
          src="/img/icone-formation.png" 
          height="100%" 
          width="100%" 
          onclick="document.getElementById('f3').style.display ='initial'; 
                   document.getElementById('f1').style.display ='none';  
                   document.getElementById('f2').style.display ='none'; 
                   document.getElementById('f4').style.display ='none'; 
                   document.getElementById('f5').style.display ='none';
                   document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('id', 'press');">
</button>

<button id="btn">
    <img class="" 
         src="/img/icone-formation.png" 
         height="100%" 
         width="100%" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('f5').style.display ='initial'; 
                  document.getElementById('f1').style.display ='none';  
                  document.getElementById('f2').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f3').style.display ='none'; 
                  document.getElementById('f4').style.display ='none';
                  document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute('id', 'press');">
</button>
```

Como posso fazer a mesma coisa com CSS puro?

Comment: Mais fácil dizer o que quer fazer em vez de por só o código. Este código que você postou não é pra funcionar mesmo, pois está com erros. Sugestão de leitura para elaborar melhor a questão: [ask] e [MCVE](/help/mcve). Talvez antes destes dois links compense você ler o [tour].

Comment: Pois objetivo, é através do botão mudar o contéudo visualizado...
Está funcionando corretamente, mas não é compativel com navegadores desejados. Basicamente o codigo, seleciona uma id do range (f1 f2 f3 f4 f5) atribuiobjeto da id respectiva ser mostrada e oculta as outras. Onde está o erro exatamente?

Comment: um dos problemas é você usar o mesmo ID em todos os botões.

Comment: aconselho rever todo seu código pois a forma que você está programando está totalmente ilógica. 1º cada botão seu deveria executar uma função e não um bloco de scripts. 2º não se tem mais de 1 elemento com o mesmo id. 3º as funções devem ser aplicadas aos botões e não às imagens... e por ai vai

Answer (score 7):

### Solução HTML + CSS

Segue uma solução CSS para mostrar apenas um elemento por vez. Você pode testar aqui mesmo:

```css
#cards input {
  display:none;                  /*  Vamos esconder os radiobuttons       */
  position:absolute;             /*  e tirar da tela pra nao aparecer     */
  left:-9000px;                  /*  marca de seleção de texto com mouse  */
}

#cards div {
  display:none;                  /*   As divs sao escondidas por padrao   */
  background:#fc9;
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

#cards input:checked + div {     /* Se existir um input selecionado a div */
  display:block;                 /* imediatamente seguinte (A+B) aparece  */
}

#buttons {
  clear:both;
}

#buttons label {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px 20px;
  background:#ccc;
  border:1px inset #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <input id="c1" type="radio" name="select" checked="checked"></input><div>1</div>
  <input id="c2" type="radio" name="select"></input><div>2</div>
  <input id="c3" type="radio" name="select"></input><div>3</div>
  <input id="c4" type="radio" name="select"></input><div>4</div>
  <input id="c5" type="radio" name="select"></input><div>5</div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <label for="c1">1</label>      <!--  O "label for" é uma espécie de    -->
  <label for="c2">2</label>      <!--  "controle remoto" do radiobutton  -->
  <label for="c3">3</label>
  <label for="c4">4</label>
  <label for="c5">5</label>
</div>
```

Claro que parte do CSS acima é apenas para "decorar" o exemplo. As partes importantes estão anotadas com `<!-- /* comments */ -->`.

### Solução JavaScript

Usando uma pequena função, dá para deixar o código menos repetitivo:

```js
function showDiv( cDiv ) {
  for(var i=1;i<=5;i++) document.getElementById('f'+i).className = ('f'+i)==cDiv?'show':'';
}
```

```css
#cards div {display:none}
#cards div.show {display:block}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div id="f1" class="show">1</div>
  <div id="f2">2</div>
  <div id="f3">3</div>
  <div id="f4">4</div>
  <div id="f5">5</div>
</div>

<button onclick="showDiv('f1');">[imagem]</button>
<button onclick="showDiv('f2');">[imagem]</button>
<button onclick="showDiv('f3');">[imagem]</button>
<button onclick="showDiv('f4');">[imagem]</button>
<button onclick="showDiv('f5');">[imagem]</button>
```

Comment: Alguém tinha deixado um comment pra mim ontem sobre usar a solução de css+checkbox, mas ao clicar na notificação, já tinha sido deletado e não vi quem foi. A sugestão foi pertinente. A única coisa que mudou foi o radiobutton, para termos apenas um ítem selecionado por vez.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o melhor jeito é fazer com **Javascript** ou usando a biblioteca **jQuery**.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-hide').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;

    $('.divs').hide();
    $('#f' + id).show();
  })
});
```

```css
.divs {
  display: none;
}
div#f1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-hide" id="1">DIV 1</button>
<button class="show-hide" id="2">DIV 2</button>
<button class="show-hide" id="3">DIV 3</button>
<button class="show-hide" id="4">DIV 4</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="divs" id="f1">DIV 1</div>
<div class="divs" id="f2">DIV 2</div>
<div class="divs" id="f3">DIV 3</div>
<div class="divs" id="f4">DIV 4</div>
```